# How to update record correctly?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

could anyone tell me how solved problem:

I want to update my record in db:

```
internal static void ReleaseMachine(int idMachine)
        {
            Machine machine = GetByID(idMachine);
            if (machine != null)
                machine.idWorker = null;
        }

internal static Machine GetByID(int idMachine)
    {
        return (from m in Database.Current.Machines where m.idMachine == idMachine select m).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

But when i try, then the program throws an exception:

> System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException ,
>
> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to specify state of the EF object  as EF cannot track the changes you have done to the returned object. dbcontext.Entry(machine).State = EntityState.Modified; 
dbcontext.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing idWorker is a foreign key, and you are setting the foreign key to null which isn't allowed as the foreign key will no longer match a record in the referenced table. This would create an orphaned record in the referenced table. You have to delete the Worker from the database first before you can remove the foreign key.

If you try the same thing in a SQL query on the database directly it won't allow you to set the idWorker to null either. If it does allow you to set the idWorker to null in the database directly, you may not have setup your entities correctly (nullable foreign key in your entity setup).

Comment: I cant delete Worker from db, i dont want to do anything in Worker table.

Comment: Then you need to make the foreign key property idWorker in the Machine table as nullable (in your database and in the entity), OR make Machine the foreign key for the Worker table.

Comment: Can you set the idWorker to null in the database for the same record? Using SQL (or whatever database you're using, not code)

Comment: Ok, i solve the problem in another way. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Hakunamatata, this is a flush/close issue, solve

```
dbcontext.Entry(machine).State = EntityState.Modified;
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Explain: Compare it with keeping a file open. You have put a NULL in your Machine table.. you opened Framework's Table object for writing.. but the Linq loads its records from the same table. It does not know you have finished writing, so it throws an exception. All you need to do is save the changes to the database. After that, the Linq expression can open the table and read from it.

Comment: Everything clear, but my dbcontext doesnt have Entry.State field. Still i dunno how to solve the problem

Comment: Ok, i solve the problem in another way. Thanks for help